# How to make this a non capturing group so it does not return empty strings

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to pull in a list of all items from a PDF that follow a specific rule.  Here is the example list I'm looking to grab.  I need all instances whether or not they have a : before or after the text, or no semicolon.

`text = "BCIW1T:  Value  - BCIW1M: Duration  - BSIW2S:     \u2022 \u2022 into Excel   Forward  Report   \u2022 Latest Solutions  BRIW1A  BCIW4A  BXIW6A  BCIW5A  BCIW2A  BCIW4A  :BFDC21A"`

My regex is:

```
    (re.findall(r"""
     ((:\b)?(?:LE|BA|BE|BM|BF|BS|B0|BT|BG|BH|BX|BC|BR|LA|LU|LB|LC|LG|LF|FB|LS|LP)
    [\w]{4,8}
    (\:?)\b)
    """, text, re.X))
```

What comes out is this:

```
 [(u'BCIW1T', u'', u''),
 (u'BCIW1M', u'', u''),
 (u'BCIW2S', u'', u''),
 (u'BCIW1A', u'', u''),
 (u'BCIW4A', u'', u''),
 (u'BCIW6A', u'', u''),
 (u'BCIW5A', u'', u''),
 (u'BCIW2A', u'', u''),
 (u'BCIW4A', u'', u''),
 (u'BCFU1A', u'', u''),
 (u'BCIK1A', u'', u''),
 (u'BCIQ1A', u'', u''),
 (u'BCIV1A', u'', u''),
 (u'BCIO1A', u'', u''),
 (u'BCGW1T', u'', u''),
 (u'BCI31A', u'', u'')]
```

Where do I add the non capture group for this specific Regex?  Thanks!

Comment: Remove outer `(...)` and turn all capturing groups into non-capturing.

Comment: I've added a ?: to the (\:?)\b) portion which eliminated one of the empty strings. But can't seem to findout where to add the other non capture group

Comment: A non-capturing group has `(?:....)` syntax. See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/i4KacT).

Comment: Thanks very much it worked!